# how to get a cSimpleModule from cModule in OMNet++ with C++?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have a compound module contain simple modules (R = receiver_1 + receiver_2), and my network contain 2 modules (R + R1) the both of them are the same (class R), I want to access to the simple modules of the two with C++, I tried to use:

```js
cModule *test = getModuleByPath("Network.R");
cSimpleModule *test1 = test->getSubmodule("receiver_2", 6);
```

But naturally I had an error told me that " invalid conversion from 'cModule*' to 'cSimpleModule*'" in the second line. So how could I access to the cSimpleModule of the cModule? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getSubmodule()` returns the pointer to a `cModule` object so you should cast the result into the pointer to `cSimpleModule` using `check_and_cast`:

```
cModule *test = getModuleByPath("Network.R");
cSimpleModule *test1 = check_and_cast<cSimpleModule *> (test->getSubmodule("receiver_2"));
```

Moreover, the second argument in `getSubmodule()` is using only if a compound module contains **a vector** of submodules. Based on your description there is no vector, so I suggest omitting this argument.

Comment: Ooh! thanks to your answers here and here too [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503266/how-do-i-call-a-parameter-for-a-compound-module#) , about the compound module doesn't have C++ code, you saved my time.